# issue with devise views rendered form a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i designed a custom form for my devise registration . but when ever i try to create a new user , devise doesn't post the data to the database and doesn't create the user .

i follow the devise documentation

in my application controller i have

```
 def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
```

i made a partial in devise name:" _signup.html.erb"  with the custom form and render it in devise/registration/new

```
<%=render :partial => '/devise/signup', :locals => {:resource => resource}%>
```

there's no error display when i sign up 
only in the log and when check the rails console no user was created . Need some help to figure out how to fix it .

```
Started GET "/users/sign_up?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=P0zVBHBKE2Ee8V3cRwtIJwAtO2txEaWEV3hGsRcqfno%3D&u
ser%5Bfirst_name%5D=Obed&user%5Bfirst_name%5D=lorisson&user%5Bemail%5D=obed.lorisson%40gmail.com&user%5Bpasswo
rd%5D=[FILTERED]&user%5Bpassword%5D=[FILTERED]&commit=Join+spotlight+Now" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-20 12:11:40
 -0400
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"P0zVBHBKE2Ee8V3cRwtIJwAtO2txEaWEV3hGsRcqfno=", "user"=>{"fi
rst_name"=>"lorisson", "email"=>"obed.lorisson@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Join spotligh
t Now"}
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered devise/_signup.html.erb (15.6ms)
  Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (46.9ms)
  Rendered shared/_header.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered shared/_flash_messages.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 156ms (Views: 156.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Signup forms

```
  <%= form_for(@user, :url => user_registration_path(@user)) do |f| %>

                                <%= devise_error_messages! %>

                                    <fieldset class="form_division">
                                        <div class="personal">
                                            <div class="controls">
                                              <%= f.text_field :first_name,  placeholder: 'first name ',:required => "true"%>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="personal">
                                            <div class="controls">
                                              <%= f.text_field :first_name,  placeholder: 'last name ',:required => "true"%>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                   </fieldset>

                                    <div class="group">
                                        <div class="circle">
                                            <span>2</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <h3>Your account credentials</h3>
                                    </div>

                                   <fieldset class="form_division">
                                        <div class="credential">

                                            <div class="controls">
                                               <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true ,placeholder: 'Email'%>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="credential">
                                            <div class="controls">
                                              <%= f.password_field :password, placeholder: 'Password' %>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="credential">
                                            <div class="controls">
                                              <%= f.password_field :password, placeholder: 'Password comfirmation' %>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </fieldset>

                                    <div class="actions">
                                        <p>By signing up, you agree to our <span><a href="">terms</a></span> of use and <span><a href="">privacy policy</a></span> </p>

                                        <div class="shared_links">
                                          <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="controls">
                                          <%= f.submit "Join spotlight Now", class: 'btn-signup animated wobble' %>
                                           <!--<a href="" class="btn-signup">join spotlight now</a>-->
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                <% end %>
```

rendered this is what it look like

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users" class="new_user" id="new_user" method="post">
```

Comment: Why do you not simple create the devise views (rails generate devise:views)? After that you can customize the existing templates..

Comment: yes i tried to do that , the reason why , it's because when for example somebody try to create an account and the form refresh without posting it's gonna redirect to the devise form , that i don't want . instead i go this route.

Comment: hmm but if you overwrite the templates, it should display the stuff you´d like..or do I have misunderstood something?

Comment: did you ever try to customize the devise generate views ? i try that in another project it was not working for me , so because i learn that from the other project. that why i go with the partial instead., one thing by design , my signin , sign up is on a single page . [example](http://fast-plateau-1053.herokuapp.com/login)

Comment: I always customize the devise views :). That was never a problem for me..

Comment: did you see the example link that i put for you to see what i intended to do?

Comment: yes..but what´s the problem? you could create a view and render the different partials..sign in, sign up, and so on..hmm

Comment: the prob the sign up form doesn't post the data and create the user .

Answer (score 0):

Post your custom sign-up form, it seems like you're submitting to the wrong path.  It looks like you're sending the data as a GET request:

```
Started GET "/users/sign_up?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_t.......
```

It should (roughly) look like this:

```
Started POST "/users?params......
```

When rendered, your form should look something like this:

```
<form action="/users" id="new_user" method="post" >
...
</form>
```

Comment: just post the sign up form